# How do I set it up so that only my player and an object have a physics body?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Creating a game like Doodle Jump, except for bouncing off platforms, my hero bounces off objects to collect points and progress in the game. As my hero "bounces off" the object, I set it to removeFromParent and it is working like it should. However, if my hero misses the object and accidentally hits the wall or ground, the object disappears as well which is odd because my ground doesn't have a physics body.

Here is my code for my GameScene:

```
 import SpriteKit

 var player: Player!
 var ground: Ground!
 var snowflake: Snowflake!
 var isFingerOnPlayer = false
 var gameOver = false
 var playerTouched = false
 var touching: Bool = false
 var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil
 let xPlayerForce: CGFloat = 40
 let yPlayerForce: CGFloat = 50
 var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()

 struct Collision {
    static let player: UInt32 = 1
    static let snowflake: UInt32 = 2
 }

 class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        player = Player()
        player.position = CGPointMake(20, 150)
        addChild(player)

        ground = Ground()
        ground.position = CGPointMake(10, -37)
        addChild(ground)

        player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
        player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 500.0
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        player.physicsBody?.mass = 0
        player.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -3.0)

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)
        snowflake = Snowflake()
        addChild(snowflake)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
            lastTouch = touchLocation

            player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = snowCategory
            player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
            player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory
            player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        }
    }

    func touchedPlayer() {
        playerTouched = true
        snowflake.removeFromParent()
        player.bounceOff()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        lastTouch = nil
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        lastTouch = nil
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if let touch = lastTouch {
            var xForce: CGFloat = 0.0
            var yForce: CGFloat = 0.0
            let xTouchOffset = (touch.x - player.position.x)
            let yTouchOffset = (touch.y - player.position.y)

            if xTouchOffset > 0.0 {
                xForce = xPlayerForce
            } else if xTouchOffset < 0.0 {
                xForce = -xPlayerForce
            } // else we do nothing

            if yTouchOffset > 0.0 {
                yForce = yPlayerForce
            } else if xTouchOffset > 0.0 {
                yForce = -yPlayerForce
            }
            // here you can choose whether you want it to push
            // the player node down, using similar code from the
            // above if statement

            let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: yForce)
            player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
        }
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        touchedPlayer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of the fact that it's not clear what is snow flake entity.

There is a code:

```
 self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

You have an edge around your frame.

From the description:

Creates an edge loop from a CGRect. Edges have no volume and are intended to be used to create static environments. **Edges can collide with body's of volume**, but not with each other.

In the method 
        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
use `contact.contactBodyA.categoryBitMask` to ignore this contact.(Should be zero).

Comment: That is why there is a contact when the player touches walls & ground.

Comment: Could you explain this a little further? Do I need a variable?

Comment: You may use contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask